# Did CDMS identify dark matter?

Tags: particle-physics, dark-matter

A recent paper by the CDMS collaboration ([PRL here](http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v111/i25/e251301) and [free text here](http://cdms.berkeley.edu/CDMSII_Si_DM_Results.pdf)) makes this statement in the abstract:

> This blind analysis of 140.2 kg day of data taken between July 2007 and September 2008 revealed three WIMP-candidate events...The probability that the known backgrounds would produce three or more events in the signal region is 5.4%.

I am not part of the particle physics communities or the dark matter communities so my questions are:

1. Is this convincing evidence for the existence of WIMPs?
2. What does this say, if anything, about the overall composition of dark matter?  I.E. is this convincing evidence that a large fraction of dark matter is from WIMPs?

Comment: 1) arXiv:1306.3983, 1306.5534 No dark matter <BR>
2) arXiv:1310.4009 Milgrom acceleration can be empirically sourced. arXiv:1306.3983 = http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.3983

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The excesses have looked convincing to many people but they don't look convincing anymore. Last October, LUX in South Dakota presented the results of their superior analysis

> http://motls.blogspot.com/2013/10/fiat-lux.html?m=1
>   http://motls.blogspot.com/2013/10/dark-matter-wars-are-over-lux-safely.html?m=1

which safely excluded the theories of WIMP dark matter directly suggested by CDMS II Si and other experiments. The complete and pure absence of a signal in LUX shows almost certainly that the excesses in CDMS II Si and other experiments were due to some overlooked background (non-dark-matter-related) processes.

WIMP is still plausible and attractive as a model of dark matter. But there's no evidence one way or another which is why physicists keep on studying it and other models as well, including e.g. those of the [sterile neutrino dark matter](http://motls.blogspot.cz/2014/02/signal-of-neutrino-dark-matter.html?m=1) or axions.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the paper you cite, but you quote a $p$-value of $5.4 \%$ which is not conclusive at all. Given that there are many experiments searching for dark matter, a fluctuation like this is extremely likely to happen by pure chance. This is known as look-elsewhere effect. Even without considering this effect, a $p$-value of $5.4 \%$ is nothing to get excited about.

In order to not proclaim a discovered particle every now and then and subsequent realization that it was just a statistical fluctuation, tight requirements for a particle discovery have been set:

To claim "observation" of a new particle, a $3 \sigma$ effect needs to be observed. The chance that this happens by a pure statistical fluctuation is $0.3 \%$. "Discovery" of a new particle is claimed when a $5 \sigma$ effect is observed in data. The probability of this being just due to a fluctuation is $3 \cdot 10^{-7}$.

Note that different standards exist, the agreement of $3 \sigma$ and $5 \sigma$ is arbitrary and it does not protect you from potential mistakes in your analysis. For example, the superluminal neutrinos were reported to be a $\sim 6 \sigma$ effect, but hardly anyone believed it, not because of statistical fluctuation, but because of systematic errors.